# Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, validation

I'm trying to use regular expression right now and I'm really confuse. I want to make some validation with this regular expression :

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_.][A-Za-z0-9_ ]*
```

I want to make it so there is a limit of character (32) and I want to "match" all the string.

ex:

string : ".hello hello"
-this should work

string : ".hello hello /.."
-This should be rejected because of the /..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_.][A-Za-z0-9_ ]{0,31}$
```

Comment: I'd start a debate about whether the "match all the string" requirement means that \Z should be used instead of $, but it's way past my bed-time, so I won't :-)

Answer (score 0):

From 0 to 32 chars:

> ^[\w\d_.]{0,32}$